# Mysql Show Create Trigger - Trigger Name Output

Tags: mysql, formatting, settings

I have two mysql databases that I'd like to keep in sync.  When I run

```
show create trigger tr_del_EmailHash;
```

from a mysqli connection from a local web page I get slightly different output from each database in that one returns the trigger name in single quotes like this:

```
CREATE trigger `tr_del_EmailHash` before DELETE
...
```

and the other returns the trigger name without quotes like this:

```
CREATE trigger tr_del_EmailHash before DELETE
...
```

Since I'm trying to store these in source control and be able to diff schema across platforms, this difference is very undesirable. The mysqld.cnf files and the mysql server variables are the same on each server, so I'm at a loss for where to look for what controls whether or not the name of a trigger gets quoted or not by "show create trigger" queries.  Can anyone provide some helpful suggestions as to where I should be looking or where this can be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoting behaviour for `show create`-statements is controlled with the [`sql_quote_show_create`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_quote_show_create) configuration setting:

> If enabled (the default), the server quotes identifiers for SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW CREATE DATABASE statements. If disabled, quoting is disabled. This option is enabled by default so that replication works for identifiers that require quoting.

Specifically for triggers, this unfortunately only works for MySQL 8, and only applies to the trigger and table name, not the trigger body. Earlier versions will quote the names as you entered them (which might be under your control, and especially involves the body anyway). This may cause trouble though if you mix MySQL 8 and earlier versions (where some modify the code, others don't), so you may have to decide for one congruent naming schema and adjust that setting accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I checked that before asking the question and the variable seems to have no effect on show create triggers (but does indeed affect the quoting of create table output). I'm still puzzled.

Comment: You are right, for triggers, this setting only has an effect on MySQL 8. If you are mixing 8 and earlier versions, you will probably have to use a naming schema that works everywhere. (You need it for the body anywhy and/or need to recreate the trigger code from your source control (once)).

Comment: Thank you again. I think you may be right and I'll give that a try and update here in a day or so.

Comment: The mysql 'show create trigger' output does depend upon whether or not the trigger was created with or without quotes around the trigger name.  My migration tool must have added quotes. A solution, for older versions of MySql anyway, is to re-create the triggers with quotes or without as desired.  I'll mark your answer correct since you say it works for mysql 8.